# How to fix ValueError: uncoverted data remains: in datetime conversion (from json) - Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Trying to take date parameters in a flask app and I get hit with this error

`ValueError: unconverted data remains:  0530 (India Standard Time)`

The date input string is of the format:

`Mon Feb 25 2019 10:31:13 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

The error is getting thrown in the format input of

`%a %b %d  %Y %X %Z`

If i try another date format

`%a %b %d  %Y %H:%M:%S %X %Z`

I get bombed with another error

`error: redefinition of group name 'H' as group 8; was group 5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string format should be `"%a %b %d %Y %X %Z%z"`. Missing `%z` at the end of the string.

Edit:
I tried this way:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_str = "Mon Feb 25 2019 10:31:13 GMT+0530"
>>> datetime.strptime(date_str, "%a %b %d %Y %X %Z%z")
datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 25, 10, 31, 13, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 19800), 'GMT'))
```

Comment: returns `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%a %b %d %Y %X %Z%z'`